# Removing symbols between letters Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to remove certain symbols from a string. I only want to remove symbols that are between letters. If my question wasn't clear enough then here are some examples:
**symbols are `@31!`**

**Input**

```
@@He11o Wor1d!
!!T3ach !m3
@13!
```

**Expected Output**

```
@@Heo Word!
!!Tach !m3
@13!
```

Can you point me in the right direction? I'm not expecting you to do it for me. I know this can be done with regex and with for loops but regex seems a bit difficult for a beginner like myself. Here's what I'm working on right now:

```
string = '@@He11o Wor1d!'
string_copy = string
symbols = "@31!"
for char in symbols:
    string_copy = string_copy.replace(char, "")
```

I'm aware that this script replaces all symbols

Comment: whats your input and whats your output? write it plz

Comment: why do you not add a check to it then that makes sure they follow and are followed by a letter? Not that this would be the best way to do it, but for you the *obvious*

Comment: I'd still recommend regular expressions in conjunction with `str.replace()`.

Comment: @DRPK This is what the first three lines are. On the left the input and after the `=` sign the desired output

Comment: @Ev. Kounis How can I do that? I've googled it and searched through stackoverflow but no success so far

Comment: Out of curiosity what's with the downvotes? Please explain

Comment: @DRPK I've separated input from output for better clarity

Comment: `(?<=[a-z])[@13!]+(?=[a-z])` replace with nothing.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I've actually converted my comment into an answer below with a full explanation of the regex.

Answer (score 4):

[Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) are definitely scary at first, but it's worth trying to learn them, as they end up being very useful. What you want in this case is:

```
import re
string = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])[@31!]+(?=[a-zA-Z])', r'\1', string)
```

[Let's look at what this does.](https://regex101.com/r/SMgOmr/2)

[`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) is similar to `str.replace`, but it uses regular expressions.

`[a-zA-Z]` matches any letter.

`[@31!]+` matches one or more of the listed symbols.

> +
>   causes the resulting RE to match 1 or more repetitions of the preceding RE.

`(?=[a-zA-Z])` is a lookahead assertion for a letter. This means that the match is followed by a letter, but the letter is not part of the match.

> (?=...)
>   matches if ... matches next, but doesn’t consume any of the string. This is called a lookahead assertion. For example, Isaac (?=Asimov) will match 'Isaac ' only if it’s followed by 'Asimov'.

So `([a-zA-Z])[@31!]+(?=[a-zA-Z])` matches a letter followed by one or more symbols from the list. This match is followed by a letter, but the match does not include the letter.

`\1` is a back-reference to the parenthesized group in the regular expression, in this case `[a-zA-Z]`. That's what we want to replace what we found with.

(the `r`s before the strings are to make them raw strings, which often helps when using regular expressions.)

**Edit:**

As @ctwheels pointed out, [you can also use a lookbehind assertion rather than a backreference](https://regex101.com/r/SMgOmr/1):

```
string = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])[@31!]+(?=[a-zA-Z])', r'', string)
```

Comment: You could add a link to regex101

Comment: Thank you very much, this information is also very useful

Comment: @AnttiHaapala added links

Answer (score 3):

This is tricky to do correctly. Although I generally prefer to avoid regex unless they're necessary, this is definitely a case where they make the job a *lot* easier. But anyway, here's a non-regex solution.

We use the standard [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function to break the input string up into three kinds of groups: 'A' groups contain letters, 'S' groups contain the special symbols, 'O' groups contain anything else. Then we scan over the groups, copying them to the `result` list unless the group is an 'S' group and it has an 'A' group immediately before it and immediately following it. Finally, we join the copied groups back into a single string.

In order to make it easier to check the following group, we add a "fake" group of `('O', '')` to the end of the list of groups. That way every real group has a following group.

```
from itertools import groupby

symbols = '@31!'

def keyfunc(c):
    if c in symbols:
        return 'S'
    elif c.isalpha():
        return 'A'
    else:
        return 'O'

def remove_symbols(s):
    groups = [(k, ''.join(g)) for k, g in groupby(s, keyfunc)] + [('O', '')]
    result = []
    prev = 'O'
    for i, (k, g) in enumerate(groups[:-1]):
        # If a group of symbols has an alpha group on both sides, don't copy it
        if not (k == 'S' and prev == 'A' and groups[i+1][0] == 'A'):
            result.append(g)
        prev = k
    return ''.join(result)

# Test

data = '''\
@@He11o Wor1d!
!!T3ach !m3
@13!
lala@@@@ 
'''

expected = '''\
@@Heo Word!
!!Tach !m3
@13!
lala@@@@
'''
print('Data')
print(data)

print('Expected')
print(expected)

print('Output')
for s in data.splitlines():
    print(remove_symbols(s))
```

**output**

```
Data
@@He11o Wor1d!
!!T3ach !m3
@13!
lala@@@@ 

Expected
@@Heo Word!
!!Tach !m3
@13!
lala@@@@

Output
@@Heo Word!
!!Tach !m3
@13!
lala@@@@
```

Comment: I have to admit that this seems a bit tricky, but if it works it works! :) I will try and work through this and see if I can make myself understand everything. Thank you

Comment: @Innit2 My pleasure. I freely admit that this is fairly advanced code, but it _is_ a tricky problem to solve correctly. I could write a solution that doesn't use `groupby`, but it would be much longer and (IMHO) harder to follow. `groupby` and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) are a bit scary at first, but they're so useful that it's definitely worth playing with & getting comfortable with them. And there's less of a learning curve than with regex. :D

Comment: This is the best answer to show that you *don't* do these without regular expressions. It just gets too complicated.

Comment: @Innit2 So in the end it is easier to just learn to read the regular expression syntax - it can still be easier to see in a glimpse what it does - this one on the other hand, is very hard to understand at first even to a very seasoned Python developer.

Answer (score 2):

### Code

[See this regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/H156UK/2)

```
(?<=[a-z])[@13!]+(?=[a-z])
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
@@He11o Wor1d!
!!T3ach !m3
@13!
```

#### Output

```
@@Heo Word!
!!Tach !m3
@13!
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?<=[a-z])` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes is a letter between `a` and `z`
- `[@13!]+` Match one or more characters present in the set `@13!`
- `(?=[a-z])` Positive lookahead ensuring what follows is a letter between `a` and `z`

Using `i` flag makes the pattern case-insensitive, thus `a-z` also matches `A-Z`

---

### Usage

```
import re
regex = r"(?<=[a-z])[@13!]+(?=[a-z])"
result = re.sub(regex, "", string, 0, re.IGNORECASE)
# re.IGNORECASE can be replaced with the shortened re.I
```

**or** (flag in the regex as opposed to passed to the function)

```
import re
regex = r"(?i)(?<=[a-z])[@13!]+(?=[a-z])"
result = re.sub(regex, "", string)
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Comment: btw your link is to a different version of the regex, intentional?

Comment: You can also add the `i` in flags

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the second version of the link defaults to python.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I've added a new section under usage. Is this what you're referring to? I've also added a comment under the first usage.